# Using Background Image to Display An Image in BooStrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I just finished building part of my website using Twitter's BootStrap, but am looking on ways to improve it. This module has an image of **known width** but **unknown height** (image height will vary but has fixed width) and has text on top of the image. I originally built this by having an image tag inside a div, then using `position:absolute; top:0;` to move a layer a text above it.

I don't like the idea of using `position:absolute;`. My alternative solution is to treat the image as a background of a div that contains the text. However, by doing so, I have encountered two problems:

1. I don't know how to specify the height of the div as this is a
   variable based on the height of the image. The width will always be
   of span4 (300px). Each image will only have a few words at most
   therefore not enough to take up the entire vertical space of the
   div.
2. As the browser width shrinks, part of the background div gets
   cropped off. This is because BootStrap is trying adjust for
   responsiveness. How would I fix this?

I am completely stumped, and I feel that this alternative solution is not possible without being able to define a definite height. Is there a better alternative?

My code:

```
<div class="span4 cell">
    This is a placeholder image
</div>

.cell { background: url(http://www.placehold.it/300x200) no-repeat; }
```

Just to be clear, here is an image of what I am trying to create:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/LstdK65j)***................................

HI now used to this

```
.span4.cell { 
background:url("http://www.placehold.it/300x200.jpg") no-repeat;
width:300px;
height:200px;
 }
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/LstdK65j)***

Comment: The height of my image will change. It will not always be 200px. As I am using BootStrap, I don't think setting a fixed width is wise as it will have scaling issues when I resize.

Comment: @Jon now you can define min-width or min-height

Comment: How do I define the min-height without knowing the height of my images though? My images will range from a height of 100px to 750px. The width will all be 300px or span4.

Comment: If I define a min-height that is greater then my image, then my .cell div will have a large empty space below it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css code. It set height as auto.
remove if you don't want border.

```
.cell {
background:url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/klttw.jpg") no-repeat;
width:300px;
height:200px;
border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Try this demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sselvamani22/mwcTx/)

Comment: The height of my images will always be changing therefore I won't be able to set a hard height on my div. I think that this approach is impossible as a div requires a height/width and I cannot provide a height in a pure CSS solution.